# Implementing Remove method Java

Tags: java, object, junit, arraylist

I'm working with implementation of a few classes but I cant seem to get one part of it working.
I'm using `Junit` to check if my implementations are correct or not and I only have one error left to correct.

This is the part I cant seem to get right, as stated in the description I'm supposed to implement a `remove` method but as far as I can tell it doesn't actually remove the `x`:

```
/**
 * Removes the specified element from this set if it is present. 
 * post: x is removed if it was present
 * @param x the element to remove - if present
 * @return true if the set contained the specified element
 */
public boolean remove(Object x) {
    return false;
}
```

Here is my current code:

```
public boolean remove(Object x) {
    if(super.remove(x)){
        if( maxElement == x ){ 
            updateMax();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void updateMax() {
    E newMax = set.get(0);
    for ( E x : set){
        if (x.compareTo(newMax) > 0) {
            newMax = x;
        }
    }
    maxElement = newMax;
}
```

But it wont work as intended.

I'm implementing this class from another class, that's why I use super.
And the other class which also had the same remove part worked with the same code snippet.

Here is all the source code:

MaxSet class which I'm trying to implement:

```
package set;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class MaxSet<E extends Comparable<E>> extends ArraySet<E> {
private E maxElement;


public MaxSet() {
    super();
}


public E getMax() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    return maxElement;
}


public boolean add(E x) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        maxElement = x;
    } else if (x.compareTo(maxElement) > 0) {
        maxElement = x;
    }
    return super.add(x);
}


public boolean remove(Object x) {
        if(set.contains(x)){
            set.remove(x);
            return remove(x); // true if the set contained the specified element
        }
        return super.remove(x);
    }


public boolean addAll(SimpleSet<? extends E> c) {
    return super.addAll(c);
}
}
```

ArraySet parent class:

```
package set;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class ArraySet<E> implements SimpleSet<E> {
protected ArrayList<E> set;

public ArraySet() {
    set = new ArrayList<E>();
}

public boolean add(E x) {
    if(!set.contains(x)) {
        return set.add(x);
    }
    return false;

}

public boolean remove(Object x) {   
    if(set.contains(x)){ 
        return set.remove(x);
    }
    return false; //?
}

public boolean contains(Object x) { 
    if(set.contains(x)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    if(set.isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public int size() {
    return set.size();
}

public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return set.iterator();
}

public boolean addAll(SimpleSet<? extends E> s) {
    Iterator<? extends E> it = s.iterator();
    boolean changed = false;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        changed = changed || add(it.next());
    }
    return changed;
}
```

}

Comment: Please don't link to pastebin instead of including the source in your question. Pastebin links don't last forever, which means that when they expire this question loses all context.

Comment: Didn't want to clutter up with too much code, should I just post everything here then?

Comment: It will always return false, right? Aww, Abu spoiled it.

Comment: @Rob post here. Have you trying returning the result after the if? Is your 'set' field from the parent? If yes, you are probably removing the same element twice, that's why in the second it gives false.

Comment: @Rob ,look at the parent's JavaDoc. It's the same contract. So why do you override it?

Comment: @Rob Forget my last comment ^^ You have to touch the MaxElement inside the remove method.

Comment: -1 Please post the minimal code inline. Remove the extra comments and the stuff that isn't used/touch/relevant.

Comment: @Rob after your edit: Be careful .. set.get(0) may return `null`.

Answer (score 2):

you're actually fine.  just a typo that you don't decrement/update your "max" variable on remove.  that's why you are getting the "wrong value of max" assertionError.

Comment: oh wait, i also thought you did this edit:  if(set.contains(x)){
            return set.remove(x); // true if the set contained the specified element
        }

Comment: The parent class already does that logic. So doing it in both cases is code-smell. In fact, I would argue that `set` in the superclass should be *private* to even prevent this situation from occurring ..

Comment: true but i'm not judging the code ... just helping point him to the real issue as to why originally one of his tests was failing.

Comment: I second pst. Touching `set` directly is part of the problem that led to the failing test, if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for something like this:

```
public boolean remove(Object x) {
    if(super.remove(x)){
        if( maxElement == x ){ /* find new maxElement here */ }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That will just give him the same "Wrong value of max" error. I think it needs to be updated as fduso said

Comment: @Michael That's why I wrote *"find new maxElement here"* ... I'm not doing *all* the work for him.

Comment: @Rob Mind the edit ... I mistakenly had `set.remove` in the first version. If you post how you implemented the "find new maxElement" I'm sure we can help you further.

Comment: Well, I tried to do a foreach loop but it didn't work out that well.

Comment: @Rob Can you update your question with the code? I guess it's a minor problem.

Comment: I edit my main post, I know its wrong but I think its in the right direction.

Comment: @Rob I recommend using a little private void method doing that.

Comment: I just edit my main post. Added a void method called "updateMax". I assume that's what you meant.

Comment: Exactly, nice and clean. So it still does not what you expect?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23727/discussion-between-fildor-and-rob)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some problem with your logic, try this one out

```
public boolean remove(Object x) {
    if(set.contains(x)){
        set.remove(x);
        return true; // true if the set contained the specified element
    }
    return super.remove(x);
}
```

Comment: It gives me the error: java.lang.AssertionError: Wrong value of max:  expected:<999> but was:<1000>

Comment: @Rob Don't you have a test for the remove method on its own?

Comment: Yes, it's checking through 8 items and 2 of them give a failure (testMaxAfterMaxremove) and (testMaxAfterManyMaxremoves)

Comment: @Rob I see now. You have to change your MaxElement inside remove if the removed Object was your MaxElement.